# Mapear dados como TIME do MySQL para JAVA acima de 24 horas Exemplo (37:26:30)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, java-8

Tenho um sistema que preciso trazer do banco MySQL informações de tempo acima de 24 horas para o Java.

Usamos hibernate e está da seguinte forma;

No banco o dado está como `TIME` (37:13:36) exemplo:

```
TEMPO_REPOUSO                     time          (NULL)             YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references
```

No Mapeamento da tabela no Java está como `TIME` exemplo:

```
@Column(name="TEMPO_REPOUSO")
private Time tempoRepouso;
```

A consulta fizemos através de uma query usando springframework.

E o objeto que vai receber os dados do banco as variáveis correspondente aos dados declaramos também como TIME do `java.sql.Time`. Exemplo:

```
private Time tempoRepouso;
```

Estamos Mapeando em DTO no Java; Não consigo de forma nenhuma trafegar este dado, unica forma que veio informação foi declarando o objeto que vai receber os dados do banco como Date, mas é barrado quando no Banco possui informações de tempos maiores que 24horas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes precisamos entender dois conceitos importantes: horários e durações. Considere as frases abaixo:

- A reunião foi às duas horas da tarde
- O filme tem duas horas de duração

No primeiro caso, "duas horas" é um horário: um momento específico do dia.

No segundo caso, "duas horas" é uma duração: uma quantidade de tempo, não necessariamente relacionada a um horário específico (não é dito que horas começa ou termina, nem sequer é dito se ele de fato foi assistido).

O que pode confundir é que ambos usam as mesmas palavras (horas, minutos, segundos) e até mesmo a forma de exibição pode ser a mesma (um relógio mostra "02:00" quando são 2 horas, um cronômetro mostra "02:00" quando já se passaram 2 horas). Mas eles são conceitos diferentes.

---

Dito isso, o tipo [`TIME` do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) serve para ambos: ele tanto pode conter um horário, quanto uma duração (por isso seu *range* de valores varia entre '-838:59:59' e '838:59:59').

Já a classe [`java.sql.Time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) representa apenas um horário, e não serve para durações. Tanto que ela só aceita valores entre 0 e 23 para as horas, e valores acima disso são truncados:

```
System.out.println(Time.valueOf("25:59:59")); // 01:59:59
```

Sendo assim, não é possível mapear durações acima de 24 horas para um `java.sql.Time`.

---

No Java 8, existe uma classe específica para durações: [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). A partir do JDBC 4.2 e Hibernate 5, há suporte para `Duration`, que é mapeado para `BIGINT`, então seria necessário mudar o tipo da coluna do banco, para conter apenas um número, [correspondente ao total em nanossegundos](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-5-date-and-time/#JDBC_Mappings) (que é a precisão desta API).

---

Ou, você poderia criar um `AttributeConverter` para converter os valores para um `Duration`:

```
@Converter
public class DurationConverter implements AttributeConverter<Duration, Long> {
    @Override
    public Long convertToDatabaseColumn(Duration duration) {
        return duration == null ? null : duration.getSeconds();
    }

    @Override
    public Duration convertToEntityAttribute(Long dbData) {
        return dbData == null ? null : Duration.ofSeconds(dbData);
    }
}

...
@Column(name="TEMPO_REPOUSO")
@Convert(DurationConverter.class)
private Duration tempoRepouso;
```

Só que aí a query teria que retornar a quantidade de segundos correpondentes à duração, algo como `SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TEMPO_REPOUSO) etc`. E da forma que está, suspeito que sirva apenas para consultas (atualizações e inserções neste campo precisariam de outra conversão, como `SEC_TO_TIME` para converter a quantidade de segundos para o `TIME` do MySQL).

Comment: Nossa muitíssimo obrigado Vou testar aqui o que você mencionou, sua resposta também agregou muito conhecimento pra mim, não consegui ser específico mas no meu caso é Duração mesmo o dado que preciso trabalhar aqui.

Comment: @DiegoSouza Blz, não esqueça que, **caso funcione** e resolva o seu problema, vc pode aceitar a resposta, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Comment: Ola @hkotsubo depois de muito teste muita pesquisa, consegui resolver o problema levando sua resposta como base...

converti os dados no banco que eram Time para Long (para representar o período gravado em  segundos) e ai sim do lado do java utilizando o Long vindo do banco, transformei ele em Período usando a classe (org.apache.commons.lang.time.DurationFormatUtils) .

Muito obrigado ajudou demais!